# HTML string with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a js file where I need to construct some HTML the problem is it needs to be in a string to be parsed. Something like;

```
var myHTML="<a href='"#"' onclick='"alert("hello"); event.returnValue = false; return false;"'>"+childOrders+"</a>"
```

I have tried lots of combinations of quotes but just cannot get it to work.

Thanks for the help,
Chris

Comment: Exciting! Which answer will he accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape quotes within a string by putting a backslash in front of them, like so:

```
myString = "A string with \"quotes\" in it.";
```

The above will result in the string `A string with "quotes" in it.`

**EDIT:** As for the quotes inside the onclick attribute, I would suggest using single quotes, so your code would look like this:

```
var myHTML="<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"alert('hello'); event.returnValue = false; return false;\">"+childOrders+"</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for this...worked just as I needed. Thanks to everybody who offered a solution!

Answer (score 1):

try following code:

```
var myHTML="<a href='#' onclick='alert(\"hello\"); event.returnValue = false; return false;'>childOrders</a>"
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGN5R/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the mighty `\` (backslash). Escape the quotes and it will work.

```
var myHTML="<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"alert(\"hello\"); event.returnValue = false; return false;\">"+childOrders+"</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myHTML = "<a href='#' onclick='alert(\"hello\"); event.returnValue = false; return false;'>" + childOrders + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **escape** the quotes inside the string like so

```
var myHTML="<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"alert(\'hello\'); event.returnValue = false; return false;\">childOrders</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var myHTML='<a href="#" onclick=alert("hello"); event.returnValue = false; return false;>'+childOrders+'</a>'
```

This works I think. Use the single quotes on the outside so you can still use the double quotes on the inside.

Answer (score 0):

just like this

```
var myHTML="<a href='#' onclick='alert('hello'); event.returnValue = false; return false;'>"+1+"</a>"
```